# Ruby on Rails Help, Error Parsing `Gemfile`:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

here is the error message I got, it was working fine until I tried to install sass, I already uninstalled sass and I am still getting this error.
[image]
This is the error message when I try to run any commands in the command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change `railssource "https://rubygems.org"` to
`source 'https://rubygems.org'`